# Looking for a way to reset or clear a DataReader

Tags: vb.net, reset, datareader

Is there an easy way to reset or clear a DataReader so it can be read through more than one time?

I found a Close method but not an open method.

Please show code samples if it can be done.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A DataReader is created and returned by using a SQL statement or stored procedure. In simple terms the DataReader is basically a cursor in the database data. If you want to use it again, recreate it again.